# How to deal with Unicode character ʿ (U+02BF)?

Tags: symbols, unicode

I have to include the name "ʿĀ’ishah". However, the first symbol "ʿ" does not appear.
Could anyone help me with this problem? Thanks a lot.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
ʿĀ’ishah
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have `MODIFIER LETTER LEFT HALF RING`, `ʿ` on the left and `RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`, ` ’` on the right. Is that intended?

Comment: Did you want left quote (U+2018) to match the right quote? `‘Ā’`

Comment: Hi, exactly, I want to have the left half ring to appear. This symbol ʿ does not appear and provokes a latex error too.

Comment: You are using pdflatex with legacy 8-bit latin fonts, so you could declare `ʿ` on input but the fonts have no such character, so what do you want to output? You could approximate with a left quote: `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02BF}{‘}` ??

Comment: U+02BF is semantically and graphically different from a left quote (but a left quote can be used as a substitute in certain cases). You need a font that supports this character and compile with a Unicode-aware LaTeX variant.

Comment: \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02BF}{‘} works! Many thanks.

Comment: Hi Jasper, thanks for the suggestions as well!

Comment: Lookig online I suspect you want the same for the right quote  U+02be MODIFIER LETTER RIGHT HALF RING  ʿĀʾishah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using pdflatex with legacy 8-bit latin fonts, so you could declare `ʿ` (modifier letter left half ring) on input but the fonts have no such character.

You could approximate with a left quote:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02BF}{‘}
```

Then

`ʿĀ’`

would work without error, or you could directly use a left quote as input:

`‘Ā’`

You may also want the matching behaviour on the right so
U+02be MODIFIER LETTER RIGHT HALF RING approximated by U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02BE}{’}
```

would allow `‘Ā’` and `ʿĀʾ`

Answer (score 3):

You can find the character in the mathscinet package. as \lasp

```
\usepackage{mathscinet}
\lasp
```

Comment: It also has `\rasp` (as right half ring).

Comment: You have `\lsap` in your first sentence.  Should be `\lasp`; please fix.

Comment: Good solution! Thank you!!

Comment: @barbarabeeton you're right thankyou!